# How can I detect when browser is visible from JS on IOS?

Tags: javascript, ios

For example, if I have a mailto link on my page, can I detect when the browser comes back to the foreground after they have sent their email?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **focus** and **blur** event handlers on the **window object** to track if the window gets or loses focus, after the user clicks send, to send the mail....

```
window.addEventListener("focus", function(event) {
//respond with a custom action when the window focus's here
});
```

I would "personally" have the user focus back on a thank you page, after they mailto function completes.  and on that thank you page, place the script action.